# Get Resource Id from cost and usage report AWS using command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, sdk, cost-management

Is it possible to get Resource Id from AWS cost and usage API?

Findings

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cur/latest/userguide/cur-create.html following this URL, successfully exported AWS cost & Usage report to S3 bucket, with Resource Id
- Then retrieve the csv from the S3 bucket using below command

> ```
> aws s3 cp s3://xxxx/ C:/Projects --recursive --exclude "*" --include "xxxx.csv"
> ```

Currently we are using below java SDK method to retrieve AWS cost but it does not return Resource Id associated with the cost.

```
AWSCostExplorer.getCostAndUsage(GetCostAndUsageRequest)
```

Any alternative solutions??